# How do I attach new special methods to an instance, at __init__?

Tags: python

I would have expected the below code to raise AttributeError. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CrazyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 'b'

        def difficult_set_attribute(key, value):
            if key not in self.__dict__:
                raise AttributeError('You may not set a new attribute, unless you do it in the secret way!')

        self.__setattr__ = difficult_set_attribute


test = CrazyClass('a')
test.c = 'c'  # why doesn't this raise AttributeError?
```

Comment: Double-underscore methods aren't called on instances.

Comment: they're called on classes, and the instance is passed as the first argument; so this means I can't do it, right?

Comment: ah, found the solution because of what you said, thanks!

Comment: but my solution doesn't allow a second instance to be created, so I'll be looking to improve it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved because of what @kindall said:

```
class CrazyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 'b'

        # the assignment is only done at the first instantiation
        if CrazyClass.__setattr__ is object.__setattr__:
            def difficult_set_attribute(cls, key, value):
                if key not in cls.__dict__:
                    raise AttributeError('You may not set a new attribute, unless you do it in the secret way!')

            CrazyClass.__setattr__ = difficult_set_attribute


test = CrazyClass('a')
test.c = 'this raises AttributeError'
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that the second instance created will raise AttributeError.

Example:

```
test = CrazyClass('a')
test_2 = CrazyClass('2')
```

There's probably a solution to this that's not too complicated. I'm looking for it now.

EDIT: this is my solution, but after reading @kindal's new comment at this answer, I'll implement his solution as well:

```
class CrazyClass:
    __temporary_allow_setattr = False

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__temporary_allow_setattr = True
        self.a = a
        self.b = 'b'
        self.__temporary_allow_setattr = False

        if CrazyClass.__setattr__ is object.__setattr__:
            def difficult_set_attribute(cls, key, value):
                if key == '_CrazyClass__temporary_allow_setattr' or cls.__temporary_allow_setattr:
                    cls.__dict__[key] = value
                else:
                    raise AttributeError('You may not set a new attribute, unless you do it in the secret way!')

            CrazyClass.__setattr__ = difficult_set_attribute


test = CrazyClass('a')
test._CrazyClass__temporary_allow_setattr = True
test.c = 'this will succeed'
test_2 = CrazyClass('b')
test_2.c = 'this will fail'
```

Comment: Why does this go in `__init__` in the first place?

Comment: because otherwise the first two assignments from `__init__` would `raise AttributeError`

Comment: Then this is a classic case of an X-Y problem. That is your actual problem, not how to add per-instance methods of a class

Comment: You can define a fresh subclass of `CrazyClass` for each instance, and then you can override the special methods on each instance's class at will. The `type()` function will do this for you or you can just use `class CrazySubClass(CrazyClass)` inside a function.

Comment: @kindall I edited the answer with a solution that I found, I'll try your solution as well today or tomorrow and edit the answer again. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just define `__setattr__` to raise the error, it would work.

```
class CrazyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 'b'

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError('You may not set a new attribute, unless you do it in the secret way!')

test = CrazyClass('a')
test.c = 'c'
```